# How to reference all app dependencies through one package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to replicate the solution to package management in Node.js described by Cory House in this [nice talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrbdNhPhkMM&feature=youtu.be&t=10m15s).

His team maintains a package called Fusion which references all dependencies used across their project portfolio, and so each project simply imports this only package, which is supposed to import all dependencies as well.

I created a similar Fusion package, threw all my dependencies there, and then added Fusion to the *dependencies* section in `package.json` of my app, but I seem to be unable to `require()` the dependencies of Fusion from the app, because they are logically installed in the `node_modules` of Fusion.

How do I make this work? How can I use the dependencies of the Fusion package in my App?

Comment: did you run `npm install` after adding fusion do your package.json?

Comment: @Derek, yep, I ran it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to implement this is to explicitly re-export all packages from Fusion to the outside world.
Assuming the `package.json` of Fusion contains the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "sprintf-js": "^1.1.1"
  },
```

**Variant 1**:
Make Fusion export all dependencies:

```
// Fusion/index.js
module.exports.jquery = require("jquery");
module.exports.express = require("express");
module.exports.ejs = require("ejs");
module.exports.bodyParser = require("body-parser");
module.exports.sprintf = require("sprintf-js");
```

Then the application can reference all that:

```
// App/app.js
var fusion = require("fusion");
var express = fusion.express;
var bodyParser = fusion.bodyParser;
```

**Variant 2**: Export a `require` function from Fusion:

```
// Fusion/index.js
module.exports.require = _require
function _require(name) { return require(name) }
```

Which will be used in the app to import all dependencies:

```
// App/app.js
var fusion = require("fusion");
var express = fusion.require("express");
var bodyParser = fusion.require("body-parser");
```

All works fine if done either way.
More elegant solutions are welcome of course.